# How to fixed column of datatable, if number of column is more then 10

Tags: jquery, datatable

I want to fix column of data table when number of column are more than 10.

During initialization of data table, how to find out number of column?

```
DataTable({
        "bRetrieve":true,
        responsive : true,
        order: [],
        scrollX:false,
        scrollCollapse: false,
        fixedColumns:{
            leftColumns: 2
         // here I want put condition if numberOfColumn > 10 only then it will return 2  
        },
```

Comment: u can do like this `leftColumn: (numberOfColumn > 10) ? 2 : numberOfColumn `

Comment: To get the number of columns you'll perhaps want to use : `$('.mytable tr:first td').lenth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to count total length of `<td>` in first `<tr>`. (Any one row in which no `colspan` applied)

`$('#example thead th').length` will return total number of column in table.

That you need to apply the condition for `>10` and so on.

Check below example :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        scrollY: "300px",
        scrollX: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging: false,
        fixedColumns: {
            leftColumns: checkColumn()
        }
    });
});

function checkColumn() {
    console.log($('#example thead th').length);
    return $('#example thead th').length >= 10 ? 2 : 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="stripe row-border order-column" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
            <th>Col 5</th>
            <th>Col 6</th>
            <th>Col 7</th>
            <th>Col 8</th>
            <th>Col 9</th>
            <th>Col 10</th>
            <th>Col 11</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger</td>
            <td>Nixon</td>
            <td>data 1.3</td>
            <td>data 1.4</td>
            <td>data 1.5</td>
            <td>data 1.6</td>
            <td>data 1.7</td>
            <td>data 1.8</td>
            <td>data 1.9</td>
            <td>data 1.10</td>
            <td>data 1.11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett</td>
            <td>Winters</td>
            <td>data 2.3</td>
            <td>data 2.4</td>
            <td>data 2.5</td>
            <td>data 2.6</td>
            <td>data 2.7</td>
            <td>data 2.8</td>
            <td>data 2.9</td>
            <td>data 2.10</td>
            <td>data 2.11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton</td>
            <td>Cox</td>
            <td>data 3.3</td>
            <td>data 3.4</td>
            <td>data 3.5</td>
            <td>data 3.6</td>
            <td>data 3.7</td>
            <td>data 3.8</td>
            <td>data 3.9</td>
            <td>data 3.10</td>
            <td>data 3.11</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In above example, I have created a function `checkColumn()` if you want to create more code inside for validation etc.

Then it will return `int` value which will directly apply to `leftColumns:checkColumn()`

Answer (score 0):

For more 10 columns change opction "responsive" to false

```
DataTable({
       ...
        responsive : false,
       ... 
        }),
```